# Removing class from scrollspy link

Tags: jquery, dom, scrollspy

How can i remove the **active** class on this link and replace it with **active2** using jQuery?

```
<li class="contact active"><a href="#contact" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

**remove**

active {background-color: black;}

**replace**

active2 {background-color: red;}

Answer (score 0):

Use `switchClass`:

```
$( "li.contact" ).switchClass( "active", "active2");
```

For more info, see [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) link on `switchClass`.

Comment: It doesnt seem to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

**Remove old class**

```
$('li.contact').removeClass('active');
```

**Adding new Class**

```
$('li.contact').addClass('active2');
```

You can do it in a single statement using jQuery chaining feature

```
$('li.contact')
  .removeClass('active')
  .addClass('active2');
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b4aegpwb/)

```js
$('li.contact').hover(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active2');
}, function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active2').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {background-color: black;}
.active2 {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="contact active"><a href="#contact" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Hope this will help you.